# why angular-strap dropdown not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am working with Angularjs and Angular-Strap and i copy Angular-Strap code sample for DropDown.

> Inlined sibling dropdown

I configure every thing right but when i click on button an empty area expands. and new UL add to page and existing UL is invisible. 
I try to create an plunker but couldn't add Angular-Starp library to it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="test" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{mainTitle}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/bootstrap-RTL/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/motion/angular-motion.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app = "taxeeApp">
<!--a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
<a ui-sref="main">Main</a-->
<div ui-view></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-dropdown aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Click to toggle dropdown
    <br>
    <small>(using inlined sibling template)</small>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#anotherAction"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>&nbsp;Some action</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="$alert('Holy guacamole')"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;Display an alert</a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="i in ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']"><a ng-href="#action{{i}}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>&nbsp;{{i}}</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    angular.module("taxeeApp", ['ui.router','mgcrea.ngStrap.dropdown']) ;
</script>
```

I am using angular v(1.4.5) and bootstrap v(3) and angular-strap v(2.3.3).

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: your dropdown-menu class is from bootstrap?

Comment: yes this is from Angular-Strap main page

Comment: But you are using angular strap as well as bootstrap  if you refer to the dropdown-menu from angular strap there is also a class of that name in bootstrap so i'm wondering if both class are getting mixed up.

Comment: angular-starp use bootstrap css. as mention in its main page. "AngularStrap is a set of native directives that enables seamless integration of Bootstrap#^3.0 into your AngularJS#^1.2 application.

With no external dependency except the Bootstrap CSS styles"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found reason of this problem. i change my Angular-Strap version to **v(2.3.6)** and all problem resolved.......